# Should nonce be sanitized?

Tags: sanitization, nonce

The general guideline is that we should sanitize all user input before using them.

Now my questions is whether this applies to nonce or not.

Which one is correct?

`wp_verify_nonce( sanitize_text_field( $_GET['some_nonce'] ), 'some_nonce' );`

or

`wp_verify_nonce( _GET['some_nonce'], 'some_nonce' );`

Comment: Relevant issue at [github/WordPress/WordPress-Coding-Standards](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress-Coding-Standards/issues/869). TLDR: It's not necessary as explained by Fayaz below; but if your environment is throwing warnings because of the unsanitized `$_REQUEST` then use `sanitize_key()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sanitizing is required when you are inserting user input into Database or outputting it in HTML etc. Here, you are simply doing a String comparison.

`wp_verify_nonce` function checks `$nonce` value like this:

```
if ( hash_equals( $expected, $nonce ) ) {
    return 1;
}
```

For this you don't need sanitizing. So the following is fine:

```
wp_verify_nonce( $_GET['some_nonce'], 'some_nonce' );
```

> **Note:** If it generates any warning for Plugin development or any other code standard, use the `sanitize_key` function to avoid the warning, but technically it shouldn't be needed for security:
>
> `wp_verify_nonce( sanitize_key( $_GET['some_nonce'] ), 'some_nonce' );`

Comment: Note that this should check `isset( $_GET['some_nonce'] )` first to avoid an error if the query string arg is not there.

Comment: If you're building a WP plugin, you will be asked to sanitze any and all POST/GET/REQUEST - not just what goes into the database

Comment: @butlerblog of course, that's a given. But I didn't include that in the answer because the question was specific to nonce sanitization.

Comment: @Philip I was referring to the original reasoning behind Sanitizing, not what is expected in any code standard. Code standards change over time, original logic doesn't. You'll find a more detailed related discussion here: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress-Coding-Standards/issues/869

Comment: @Philip Also, you can see here that the core itself doesn't do nonce sanitization: https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.2/src/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L1271